# Ошибка из-за смайликов и шрифтов в никах телеграмм AIOGram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Мой бот составляет список инактивных пользователей, но когда ему попадаются ники с разными шрифтами вылезает ошибка типа:

```
File "d:\Python\Projects\chat_active\main.py", line 19
    db.add_message(1234, 2023-14-10 13:47:00, \u03bb\u03cd\u2115�\u13a5\u13e6 \u21e7, luntik006)
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid character '�' (U+2020)
```

я думал может нужно изменить кодировку или найти способ перевести эти шрифты на обычный.
В интернете ничего не нашел, нейросети тоже ничего не знают

Comment: Ответ помог вам?)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте, например с помощью [`ord()`](https://pythononline.ru/osnovy/funktsii-chr-ord-python) брать числовой код каждого символа и записывать ник в БД как раз этими числовыми кодами через какой-то определённый символ (например, дефис). Для расшифровки воспользуйтесь методом `split()` (*разделяет всю строку числовых кодов на коды отдельных символов*) и [`chr()`](https://pythononline.ru/osnovy/funktsii-chr-ord-python) для каждого символа. Либо делайте словарь со всеми шрифтами... Но это ужасно заморочно